# how to import csv file on hasura

Tags: postgresql, hasura, hasura-cli

Hi i am trying to import csv file in hasura
my file file directory is not found

```
postgres-# \copy jpnagar from 'c:\Users\9sand\rdlcMembersData_1.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
c:\Users\9sand\rdlcMembersData_1.csv: No such file or directory
```

am am trying to inport the data from csv to hasura in postgress sql but my file path is showing error i checked it the file path is correct

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/postgres-guides/import-data-from-csv/#step-2-connect-to-your-postgres-database

Comment: Try reversing the slashes in the file path, \  --> /.